# Laravel 7: How to calculate difference between two time format value and store in database?

Tags: php, laravel-7, difference, calculation, date-difference

I want to calculate late entry from difference between check_in time and opening_time from Settings table and store the time value in attendance table. `Time formate : 10:15:00`. The check_in and check_out time will come from request.

```
Example: 
open = 10:15:00
end = 18:00:00
check_in = 10:18:00
check_out = 17:50:00
late = open - check_in = 00:03:00
early = end - check_out = 00:10::
```

Please see below code

Settings Table

| id | opening_time | ending_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10:15:00 | 18:00:00 |

attendance table

| id | late | early |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:20:00 | 00:05:00 |

Controller:

```
public function AttendanceCSVStore(Request $request)
{
    $settings = Setting::where('id', 1)->get();
    $open = time($settings->opening_time);
    $end = time($settings->ending_time);

    for ($x = 1; $x <= $request->number; $x++) {
        $attendances = new Attendance;
        $attendances->check_in = $request->$x[4];
        $attendances->check_out = $request->$x[5];
        $csv_check_in = time($request->$x[4]);
        $csv_check_out = time($request->$x[5]);
        if( $csv_check_in > $open){
            $late_count =  $csv_check_in - $open;
            $attendances->late =  $late_count;
        }
        if( $csv_check_out < $end){
            $early_count = $csv_check_out - $end;
            $attendances->early = $early_count;
        }
        $attendances->save();
    }
    return redirect()->route('admin.attendance.manage')->with('message', 'Imported Successfully!');
}
```

This shows error `Property [opening_time] does not exist on this collection instance.`
And also this doesn't calculate and insert time in late, early column.

Can you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a collection, not a single record.

If you need a single record instead of a collection, you can get it by this way

```
$id = 1;
$settings = Setting::find($id);

echo $settings->opening_time;
```

or

```
$id = 1;
$settings = Setting::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

echo $settings->opening_time;
```

If you need a collection and iterate on it, you can do it like that (But I don't think this is what you are after)

```
$settings = Setting::where('id', 1)->get();

foreach ($settings as $setting) {
    echo $setting->opening_time;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Time difference example

```
public function index()
{
    $startTime = Carbon::parse('2020-02-11 04:04:26');
    $endTime = Carbon::parse('2020-02-11 04:36:56');

    $totalDuration =  $startTime->diff($endTime)->format('%H:%I:%S');
    dd($totalDuration);
}
```

Output: "00:32:30"

I think this is the format you are after

Comment: Thanks, got this point. Can you please check the calculation?

Comment: Thanks for helping me to solve this problem

Comment: You're welcome. You've got the key point!

Comment: If I want to select the first row of the settings table what will be that querry? The id can be change anytime. So I don't want to make the id static.

Comment: DB::table('settings')->first();